A supremum/integral inequality
Let $I$ be an arbitrary index set and for each $i\in I$ let $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n\to [0,\infty)$ be a measurable function. For each $i\in I$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ let $f_i^n:\mathbb{R}^n\to [0,\infty)$ be measurable functions such that
\begin{align*}
\int f_i^n(x)dx\xrightarrow{n\to \infty} \int f_i(x)dx
\end{align*}
for each $i\in I$. My question is: Is it true that
\begin{align*}
\int \sup_i\{f_i\}(x)dx\leq \liminf_{n\to \infty} \int \sup_i\{f_i^n\}(x)dx  ?
\end{align*}

How can $n \to \infty$ when it is the dimension of the domain space of $f_i$? What does it mean for the domain of a function to change its dimension?
